# Not Working: changing placeholder's value of input type accoring to the select value in select option

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<span style="margin-top: -2px;">    
    <select id="selectID" style="width: 150px">
    <option value="customerID">Customer ID</option>
        <option value="ECPDProfileID">ECPD Profile ID</option>
</select>

</span>

<input type="text" id="customerProfileID" placeholder="here"/>
```

I was trying to change the placeholder value according to the value selected in the select option.

I tried the following jQuery code for this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var v = $("#selectID").val();
  $("#customerProfileID").attr('placeholder', v);
  });
</script>
```

This code changes the placeholder's value only once when the page loads first time, as I know I kept it inside document ready function. I wanted to change the value of placeholder according to the value is selected in the select option. Do I need to make another call or can do from inside the document ready function, or any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#selectID').on('change', function(){
            $("#customerProfileID").attr('placeholder', $(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks all of your codes are working ... since placeholder is not recognized by IE, so I had used a small plugin for that. But this code did not work with that plugin. Then I removed the placeholder plugin and simply put value="here" instead of placeholder="here" and it worked. Thanks Rik :-)

Answer (score 1):

Put it inside `$('#selectID').change`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectID').change(function () {
      var v = $("#selectID").val();
      $("#customerProfileID").attr('placeholder', v);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks all of your codes are working ... since placeholder is not recognized by IE, so I had used a small plugin for that. But this code did not work with that plugin. Then I removed the placeholder plugin and simply put value="here" instead of placeholder="here" and it worked. Thanks Alex :-)